# laravel 5.4 sitemap error

Tags: php, laravel, sitemap

I want to install this package in my project
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap

but the installation's failed. the error is 
[image]

Anyone encountered this error. or their have other better package for laravel sitemap? any tutorial? thanks everyone :)

Comment: That error message is pretty clear. You're trying to install `spatie/laravel-sitemap ^3.3`, which requires Laravel 5.5 or higher. So you need to either upgrade to use Laravel 5.5, or use an older version of `spatie/laravel-sitemap`

Comment: Where can I find the older version of spatie/laravel-sitemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. You're trying to install `spatie/laravel-sitemap:^3.3`, which requires `laravel/framework:5.5` or higher. So you need to either upgrade to use Laravel 5.5, or use an older version of `spatie/laravel-sitemap`.

The Github repository lists the [available releases](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap/releases). I would suggest looking at `v2.4` as a starting point, as the ChangeLog for `v3.0` mentions about adding Laravel 5.5 support.

```
composer require spatie/laravel-sitemap:2.4
```

**Edit**:

You asked where to put the generator code. It isn't something you're going to want to run on every request, so I would suggest creating a route dedicated to creating the sitemap.

```
// routes/web.php

Route::get('sitemap/generate', function () {
    SitemapGenerator::create(base_url())->writeToFile($path);
});
```

Comment: Hi bro, can I ask something? where can i put this code?
SitemapGenerator::create('https://example.com')->writeToFile($path);
in my homepage controller index? or I create new controller for this .

Comment: Good question. It's not something you're going to want to run on every page request, so I would create a dedicated route, e.g.  `/sitemap/generate`, and add it in there.